# bootstrap grid won't show correctly

Tags: html, css

I want to make a bootstrap grid. I tried this grid but sometimes the images will all stack up like in the screenshot.

I am experiencing these problems when I reload the page. I can't say if the problem is from my images (resolution or something) as I am new to HTML...

HTML :

```
<!-- portfolio -->
<div id="portfolio" class="services portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="w3title">Nos appartements</h3>
        <p class="wthree-ttext">Choisissez la région désirée à l'aide du filtre</p>
        <div class="gallery_gds">
            <ul class="simplefilter">
                <li class="active" data-filter="all">Tout</li>
                <li data-filter="1">Sherbrooke Nord</li>
                <li data-filter="2">Sherbrooke Est</li>
                <li data-filter="3">Magog</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="filtr-container">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Luminous night">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="1-100-Don-Bosco-5-NC.html">
                            <img src="images/photos/exterieur/100-don-bosco-appartement-louer.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="1-100-Don-Bosco-3.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/100-don-bosco-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="1-100-Don-Bosco-1.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/100-don-bosco-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="2-2985-Ladauversiere-4-NC.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2985-la-dauversiere-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="2-2985-Ladauversiere-4.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2985-la-dauversiere-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="2-2985-Ladauversiere-3.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2985-la-dauversiere-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="2-2985-Ladauversiere-2.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2985-la-dauversiere-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="2" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="3-590-Saint-Francois-4-NC.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/590-saint-francois-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="2" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="4-1415-1425-du-Conseil-4.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/1415-1425-conseil-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>Libre immédiatement</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="2" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="4-1415-1425-du-Conseil-3.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/1415-1425-conseil-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="5-300-des-Erables-5.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/300-des-erables-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="6-2800-du-Manoir-4.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2800-manoir-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er avril 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="7-2820-du-Manoir-3.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2820-manoir-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="8-2840-du-Manoir-4-NC.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2860-manoir-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="9-2860-du-Manoir-4.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2860-manoir-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="1" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="10-2880-du-Manoir-4-NC.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/2880-manoir-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er mars 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="3" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="11-1260-Champlain-3.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/1260-champlain-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er mars 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filtr-item" data-category="3" data-sort="Busy streets">
                    <div class="agileits-img">
                        <a href="13-217-223-Calixa-Lavallee-4.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/photos/exterieur/217-calixa-lavallee-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
                            <div class="wthree-pcatn">
                                <h4>1er juillet 2019</h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- //portfolio -->
```

The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nX6l.jpg ,
The expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y53gJ.jpg .

Comment: Please share the complete explainable code, here i can see only one image container

Comment: Here I posted an edited version.

Comment: Does this occur just for specific browser(s)? Is the HTML and CSS valid? Are there any JavaScript, or other, errors reported? Are other features running on the same page?

Comment: It happens in Safari and Google Chrome. I see no other errors on the page.

Comment: Use of `col-*` classes should be preceded by a 'row' class. Try adding `row` with `filtr-container` (i guess this is not a bootstrap class).

Comment: Tried your solution but I think it is handled in the bootstrap class because it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the code as follows.

Example :

```
<img class="img-responsive " src="/project_name/images/photos/exterieur/217-calixa-lavallee-appartement-louer.jpg" alt=""  />
```